# Sublime Text 3, When I double/triple click on a word the cursor is at the beginning of the word/line

Tags: cursor, sublimetext3

On Sublime 3 editor, Whenever I double/triple click on a word the cursor is at the beginning of the word/line instead of the end.

How do I change it back to the end?.

Comment: The default commands that run when you select something put the caret at the end; if it's not doing that for you I would check and see if you have a package or plugin that's changing the defaults on you.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to very slight mouse movements while double-clicking and is by design - a little known feature !!

If you double-click a word and at the same time move the mouse very slightly to the left then the cursor will be placed on the left of the word instead of the right (which it does by default).

Try double-clicking while keeping the mouse totally still or moving the mouse very slightly to the right when you double-click and the cursor will be placed on the right of the word.